# Dividing absolute uncertainties for a range of values

Tags: error-analysis

I have a set of measurements for displacement and time. The absolute uncertainties for them are $\pm 0.005$m and $\pm 0.0167$seconds respectively.

How do I correctly find the uncertainties for velocity? I feel that I have to calculate percentage uncertainty for each pair of displacement and time, and the uncertainty will be different for every pair. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Velocity (actually here speed) is given by:

$$v= \frac {s}{t}$$

Now the percentage error in the measurement of velocity is given by:

$$ \delta v = \delta s + \delta t$$

The percentage error of say a quantity $a$ is given by:

$$ \delta a = \frac { \Delta a}{a} \times 100\%$$

So for finding the percentage error of velocity you must have velocity $v$, displacement $s$, time $t$ though you only have given the absolute errors in these quantities (displacement and time) and hence without this you cannot calculate the error (either absolute or percentage) in these quantities.

Comment: Why not? I have the absolute errors of disp. and time. I can still calculate velocity without error. And I can get the percentage errors of displacement and tiem from any pair of values. When I add these values, I get the percentage error for velocity. Right?

Comment: @curiouscase I was just trying to say that without the values of displacement and time you cannot do that though if you have them then it's possible to calculate though the value of absolute and percentage  error  in velocity would be different for different values of these.